# How do I display string data in a world map using Pygal and Python?

Tags: python, pygal

So I'm reading the Python Crash Course book, and one of its exercises was finding a custom CSV file and outputting its data into a World Map using Pygal. In the past exercises, we displayed numbers in the map, but now I'm trying to display strings, each of them called 'high income', 'low income' and so on. So far, I have this code:

```
import csv
import pygal
from pygal.maps.world import World
from country_codes import get_country_code

# Loading data
filename = 'metadata_country.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    children_list = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(children_list)    

    incomes = {}
    for data in children_list:
        try:
            country_code = get_country_code(data[4])
            child_income = data[2]
        except ValueError:
            print("Data missing for " + country_code)
        else:
            incomes[country_code] = child_income


income_levels = ['High income', 'Lower middle income', 'Upper Middle income', 'Low income']

# Filtering the child incomes dictionary   
children_high, children_upper_middle, children_lower_middle, children_low = {}, {}, {}, {}
for country, income in incomes.items():
    if income == income_levels[0]:
        children_high[country] = income
    elif income == income_levels[1]:
        children_lower_middle[country] = income
    elif income == income_levels[2]:
        children_upper_middle[country] = income
    else:
        children_low[country] = income

world_map = World()
world_map.title = 'Children income per country'
world_map.add('High income', children_high)
world_map.add('Upper Middle income', children_upper_middle)
world_map.add('Lower middle income', children_lower_middle)
world_map.add('Low income', children_low)

world_map.render_to_file('children_income.svg')
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Matheus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pygal\graph\map.py", line 83, in _plot      
    ratio = .3 + .7 * (value - min_) / (max_ - min_)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Can someone help me troubleshoot what is wrong with it? I'm new to Python and new to Pygal as well. Just doing it for the sake of curiosity. Thanks!
[Link to the .csv file if needed.](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/883f6b1d5a6d37713bcca9245667641220200318172615/c06fd0)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Actually, changing this section did the trick:

```
# Filtering the child incomes dictionary   
children_high, children_upper_middle, children_lower_middle, children_low = {}, {}, {}, {}
for country, income in incomes.items():    
    if income == income_levels[0]:
        children_high[country] = income_levels[0]
    elif income == income_levels[1]:
        children_lower_middle[country] = income_levels[1]
    elif income == income_levels[2]:
        children_upper_middle[country] = income_levels[2]
    else:
        children_low[country] = income_levels[3]
```

I was using the 'income' value from the dictionary 'incomes' before and it wasn't working for some reason. Now I passed the value as 'income_levels[index]' which returns a string, and it's working as intended. I'd still appreciate if anyone could pinpoint what caused this. Thanks!